# maximum value of minimum values in sub-array of size x

Tags: java, algorithm, sliding-window

I have given interview with one company where they asked me Sliding Window Minimum value problem as below -

```
 Find maximum value of minimum values in sub-array of size x
 e.g. arr = [2,5,4,6,8] and x = 3 then subarray would be [2,5,4], [5,4,6] and [4,6,8]. 
 The respective minimum values are 2,4 and 4. The maximum of these values is 4.
```

I have return below code but it is giving `Time Limit Exceeded` for some test

```
public static int max(int x, List<Integer> num){
 int n = num.size();
 List<Integer> minList = new ArrayList<>();
 for(int i = 0; i <= n - x; i++){
    int minVal = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int j = i; j < i + x; j++){
        minVal = Math.min(min, num.get(j));
    }
    minList.add(minVal);
  }
  return Collections.max(minList);
}
```

Can someone correct it or point out for correct one.

Answer (score -2):

The time complexity of your code is O(n*m), but there is a solution with time complexity O(n), it requires just a single pass through the array. For example, take a look [here](https://people.cs.uct.ac.za/%7Eksmith/articles/sliding_window_minimum.html).

Comment: Saying there is a solution without any hint at what that solution is, is not a *useful* answer. Might be a good comment, but it's not an answer.

Comment: Link-only answers are not [good answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231/351454).